# How to display numbers by line depending on the number in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Hi I am new to C++ and I am having problem with displaying the numbers from 1,2,3, and so on depending on the user input.

For example, if input is 3, first line of output should be 1, next line should be 2 3, and the last line should be 4 5 6. Please see below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @AviGinsburg...Yes sir, I have just tried looping, but I can't achieve my desired output.

Comment: Show your code. It's a pretty trivial task, so your code shouldn't be too long.

Comment: There's a pattern in differences between each number in horizontal lines.

Comment: Confusing ... "first line of output should be 1", but the 1st line in your not-a-'screenshot' is "1 2 4";  "next line should be 2 3", but you show "_  3 5".  Perhaps you are trying for the triangle, but is part of the requirement for the shape to be turned on its side?

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN I guess his "lines" are vertical (what we call columns), then his description matches the "screenshot" (which we would call an example).

Comment: So by "line" you actually mean "column"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [number of elements to display in the leftmost *n* columns](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%20%2B%202%20%2B%203%20%2B%20...%20%2B%20n) is exactly:

[image: 1+2+3+\ldots+n=\sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}]

So, the numbers in the first row form the [A000124](https://oeis.org/A000124) integer sequence.

Therefore, you can just add the row index to respective value of the sequence, and print it only when row index is not greater than column index.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            if(i <= j) {
                cout << j*(j+1)/2+1 + i;
            }
            cout << '\t';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[See the code live.](http://ideone.com/qxvVZk)

Comment: Don't encourage asking offf-topic questions by giving answers. You're actively hurting the quality of the site!

Comment: Why isn't this question marked as off-topic then? Downvoting good answers is discouraging too.

Comment: We're working on it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Why is this question off topic again?

Comment: @Shoe You well know why dude :)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I actually don't. Seems like a perfectly normal question about programming. I mean there might not be enough effort spent on OP's part, but the question itself is not that bad.

Comment: @Shoe Way too broad, no efforts shown, missing question, etc. Need more?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Broad? I understood the question just fine. About the missing question, "How to display numbers by line depending on the number in C++?" is right there. As I said, there seems not to be efforts on OP's part, but that's not a problem with the question itself.

Comment: So it's OK now to ask _Gimme teh codez plz_ questions in disguise? O tempora o mores :(

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ "[Well, if it might benefit someone somewhere else, who cares?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19673/307923)"

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, l=1;
    cin >> n;
    for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        int k = l;
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            if(i < j) {
                cout << " \t";
                continue;
            }
            cout << k << "\t";
            k += i;
        }
        cout << endl;
        l = l + j + 1;
    }
    return 1;
}
```